# Build on 4 inch display isn't showing black top and bottom bar

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I recently finished my app but haven't made it for the 4 inch screen yet. I decided to upload it to the appstore anyways and do the 4 inch version later. I'd like to have black top and bottom bars shown if the app is used on a 4 inch display.

I have an default image called Default-568h@2x.png but when I build it and change the simulator to 4 inch it stretches my screen and no black bars are shown. If I delete the Default-568h@2x.png it doesn't change a thing.

Anyone can help me out?

Comment: I was under the impression that they were no longer accepting iPhone apps that don't support the 4" screen. I believe it's now a requirement.

Comment: Should I in that case make if statements for pretty much everything to relocate them to my way when the app is on a iPhone 5?

Comment: I'm looking for some documentation on that and all I can find is a reference to launch screens being required in the [HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW5).

Comment: You shouldn't have to do anything. Usually judicious use of [`autoresizingMask`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/autoresizingMask) means that no coding is needed. You often don't need to put in any conditional code.

Comment: Alright thanks but unfortunately it doesn't look good on the iphone 5 simulator:(

Comment: Yeah, I didn't mean to suggest that you would get away with doing nothing, but if you're doing a lot of `if` statements in your code, you might not implementing your UI very effectively as you could. There are definitely times where you have to carefully recraft a UI based upon device dimensions, but hopefully not too often. I generally end up with a control or two that is a prime candidate for stretching and the rest move around through the magic of strings and struts (or auto sizing in iOS 6). Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting files in Xcode does not delete them from installed apps/build folders/etc.  It's extremely annoying.  If you really want your app to only run in 3.5 inch mode, delete the Default-568 file and make sure to run Clean/Clean Build Folder in Xcode, and delete the app completely off your simulator/device. It should start showing up letterboxed again.

Apple is still accepting 3.5in only submissions.

Comment: they still accepting? I'm not sure what you mean with 3.5in only submissions decided to make a couple of edits to make it run on 4 inch and then I'll have to abort this current submissions, archive it again en submit it again I guess?

Comment: A commenter above said he thought Apple would not allow app store submissions that didn't support 4 inch display.  That is not true (yet).  You can choose not to support 4 inch now if you don't want to do the extra work.  As the owner of a fancy new iPhone 5 I strongly urge you to consider support it though!  I love my 5 and it looks real cheap when apps aren't upgraded for it yet.

Comment: thanks for the advise, I took me a few hours and I think its ready for iphone 5 :) canceled the submission and submitted it again:) now lets hope my first app ever will be accepted! hehe